# omitting certain data in R to maintain overall data integrity

Tags: r, iteration, nan

I have a function that returns 50 data values, in a one column matrix, for each of 100 different data frames . However due to circumstance sometimes the function returns a "NaN" in one or more of the 50 values in a data frame . This perturbs the data as a data frame  that has one or more NaN is now considered to have 49 or 48 columns.

```
          df1        df2
         112.4563 112.4563
         110.1210 110.1210
         109.2143 109.2143
         NaN      108.1806 <- now uneven and can not perform iterations
         107.3700 107.3700
```

How can I tell my computer/ subsequent commands when iterating through these 100 50 rowed data frames to "ignore" the NaN values in a way that each of the 100 will still be able to have 50 values and are consistently iterable? Or its it even possible to have a varying iteration range- for(i in 1:(47-50). So that the computer forgives the variance in row numbers? 
this is also with respect to graphs.

Comment: How do you wish your subsequent commands to "ignore" / "handle" an `NaN` value? The point of the `NaN` type is that it represents something unusual ("not a number") and that you must determine how to handle it. **You haven't specified how to handle it.**

Comment: sorry what I meant was that I just wanted the code to "ignore/skip" the data that is NaN- this is without varying the number of rows in the column... so something like an if command: if(i=NaN): tell code to skip this value

Answer (score 0):

As someone else has noted, it can also depend on what you want to do with the NaN value. However, on answering for an interative range, you can do something like the following. I'll be using the dataframe mtcars as an example.

```
df = mtcars
length(df$mpg)
length(rownames(df))
length(colnames(df))
```

If you need to iterate over the total number of rows in your data frame, you can use length(rownames(df)). If you need to iterate over the number of columns instead, you can use length(colnames(df)).

In a for loop, you would do the following:

```
for (i in length(rownames(df)){
# iterative code
}
```

This will iterate over the total number of rows in a given data frame.